# print all binary numbers of size n using recursion

Tags: java, recursion, binary

i am trying to print all size n binary numbers, for example if size is 3 , i want to print all numbers from 0 to (2^3)-1 in binary form, below if my code implementating, it prints 000 and gives me this error

```
"Exception in thread "main" java.lang.StackOverflowError
at java.lang.String.getChars(String.java:854)
at java.lang.AbstractStringBuilder.append(AbstractStringBuilder.java:391)
at java.lang.StringBuilder.append(StringBuilder.java:119)
at java.lang.StringBuilder.<init>(StringBuilder.java:93)
at NBinary.tobinary(NBinary.java:11)
at NBinary.tobinary(NBinary.java:12)". 

String temp = str+x; is line 11
tobinary(temp, size); is line 12
```

below is my code

```
public class NBinary {

static int arr[] = {0,1};
static void tobinary(String str,int size){

    if(str.length() == size){
        System.out.println(str);
    }
    for(int x : arr){
        String temp = str+x;
        tobinary(temp, size);
    }


}

public static void main(String[]args){

    tobinary("", 3);

}

}
```

please help me find the error. thanks

Comment: Does it have to use recursion?

Comment: Did you googled `StackOverflowError`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One problem is that you are not giving any **Recursion Termination** condition. 
So the function recurses infinitely. No condition is there to cease the calling.

That is why the stack allocated for the function call runs out of space and you get  **StackOverflowError**.

See more here:

http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/StackOverflowError.html

[What is a StackOverflowError?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/214741/what-is-a-stack-overflow-error)